# What is the purpose of "do!" notation in F#?

Tags: f#

I'm a beginner in F#, so it's a simple question and maybe a duplicate, but I couldn't find the answer anywhere...

I'm reading [this LOGO DSL implementation](http://lorgonblog.spaces.live.com/Blog/cns!701679AD17B6D310!1886.entry) and I don't understand, what is the meaning of the "do!" notation in here:

```
    this.Loaded.Add (fun _ ->
        async {
            do! Async.Sleep 200
            for cmd in theDrawing do
                do! this.Execute(cmd)
        } |> Async.StartImmediate 
    )
```

Can you help?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

F# [computation expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233182.aspx) (a.k.a. "workflows") use the syntax

```
builder { expression }
```

where `expression` can contain special constructs including the various "bang" keywords like `let!` and `do!`.  Like LINQ in C# or VB, F# computation expressions are just a syntactic sugar (that desugars into method calls on the `builder`).

One of the most common types of computation expression is `async`, as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233250.aspx).

In this particular example, the `async` is being used along with `Async.Sleep` to temporarily get off the UI thread, to give the UI a chance to redraw, react to mouse events, etc.  This general technique is described more [here](http://lorgonblog.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!701679AD17B6D310!1842.entry).

Answer (score 25):

I'll only add that the `do!` notation doesn't have to be explicitly supported by the computation expression, because the same thing can be written using `let!` like this:

```
do! foo()       // Using do!
let! _ = foo()  // Equivalent using let!
```

In general `let!` us used when you have some function implemented using computation expressions and you want to call it from another computation expression of the same type. This means, that it is used for composing computation expressions. For `async` this *composition* means that you have a non-blocking asynchronous code and call it from another asynchronous workflow in some special way to make the call asynchronous.

The `let!` keyword allows you to do this and get some value as the result, while `do!` is a shortcut that you can use if the computation doesn't return anything.

A chapter from Real-world Functional Programming that discusses computation expressions (and also sequence expressions) is available as a free sample, so if you want to read a more detailed tutorial about *computation expressions* this may be a good source of infromation:

- [Chapter 12: Sequence expressions and alternative workflows](http://www.manning.com/petricek/SampleChapter12.pdf)

BTW: It should be possible to write the sample code in your question in a nicer way using the `AwaitEvent` primitive like this:

```
async { 
  let! _ = this.Loaded |> Async.AwaitEvent 
  do! Async.Sleep 200 
  for cmd in theDrawing do 
     do! this.Execute(cmd)  } |> Async.StartImmediate
```

This means the same thing - it first waits until the `Loaded` event occurs, then it waits 200ms and then it does the rest of the work. This *waiting* is special (that's why we use `let!`/`do!`, because it doesn't block the thread while waiting).

Answer (score 4):

In you case it is running the sleep expression asynchronously so the thread can do something useful rather than blocking.

In general, `let!`, `use!`, `yield!` and `do!` do the "special" processing of the containing computation expressions (whatever that is, `async` in this case). E.g. in a `seq { ... }` using `yield!` allows a sub-sequence to be merged into the output rather than being returned as a single object.

Comment: Is there a name for this notation? Where to read more about it?

Comment: "computation expressions" or "workflows"; an old (somewhat outdated) explanation is here: http://blogs.msdn.com/dsyme/archive/2007/09/22/some-details-on-f-computation-expressions-aka-monadic-or-workflow-syntax.aspx

Comment: A chapter from Real-world Functional Programming that discusses computation expressions (and also sequence expressions) is available as a free sample chapter: http://www.manning.com/petricek/SampleChapter12.pdf